# How to find Expected Value of a non-continuous distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, expectation

Problem Statement :

> The Pacific Transit #1 bus I take to campus is sometimes early and usually late. I
>   model the time the bus leaves my stop using a random variable $X$ representing the difference
>   (in minutes) between the time the bus actually leaves minus its scheduled time. A positive
>   $X$ means the bus is late, a negative $X$ means the bus is early, and $X = 0$ means the bus is
>   on time. $X$ may or may not be a whole number.
>
> The CDF of $X$ is
>
> $$
> F(y) =\begin{cases}
> 0,& y<-4\\
> \frac15+\frac1{20}y,& -4\leqslant y<0\\
> \frac25+\frac1{20}y,& 0\leqslant y<12\\
> 1,&y\geqslant 12.
> \end{cases}
> $$

From the CDF we can see that it's noncontinuous because of the jump at  $x = 0$ from $0.2$ to $0.4$.

How can I find the Expected value of $X$?

$E(X)\text{ ?}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X] &= \mathbb E(X\cdot\mathbf 1_{X<0})+\mathbb E(X\cdot\mathbf 1_{X=0})+\mathbb E(X\cdot\mathbf 1_{X>0})
\\[1ex]&= \int_{-\infty}^0 -F(x)\,\mathsf dx + 0 +\int_0^\infty (1-F(x)\,\mathsf dx\\[1ex]
&= \int_{-4}^0-\left(\frac15+\frac1{20}x\right)\,\mathsf dx + \int_0^{12} \left(1-\left(\frac25+\frac1{20}x\right)\right)\,\mathsf dx\\[1ex]
&= \int_{-4}^0\left(-\frac15 -\frac1{20}x\right)\,\mathsf dx + \int_0^{12} \left(\frac35 - \frac1{20}x\right) \\[1ex]
&= \left[-\frac15x-\frac1{40}x^2 \right]_{-4}^0 + \left[\frac35x - \frac1{40}x^2 \right]_0^{12}\\[1ex]
&= -\frac45 + \frac25 + \frac{36}5 - \frac{18}5\\[1ex]
&= \frac{16}5.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!!